# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: from java.util.regex.Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regex to remove nbsp; from my string . Following is the program.

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

     public class MyTest {

    private static final StringBuffer testRegex = 
        new StringBuffer("<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#ff6600\">Test</font></p><br><p>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#ff6600\">Test</font></p><br><p>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#ff6600\">Test</font>" +
        "<BLOCKQUOTE&nbsp;style=\"MARGIN-RIGHT:&nbsp;0px\"&nbsp;dir=ltr><br><p>Test</p><strong>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;color=#333333>TestTest</font></strong></p><br><p>Test</p></blockquote>" +
        "<br><p>TestTest</p><br><BLOCKQUOTE&nbsp;style=\"MARGIN-RIGHT:&nbsp;0px\"&nbsp;dir=ltr><br><p>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#ffcc66\">TestTestTestTestTest</font><br>" +
        "<p>TestTestTestTest</p></blockquote><br><p>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#003333\">TestTestTest</font></p><p>" +
        "<FONT&nbsp;style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR:&nbsp;#003399\">TestTest</font></p><p>&nbsp;</p>");

    //"This&nbsp;is&nbsp;test<P>Tag&nbsp;Tag</P>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("***Testing***");
        String temp = checkRegex(testRegex);
        System.out.println("***FINAL = "+temp);

    }

    private static String checkRegex(StringBuffer sample){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]+?&nbsp;[^<]+?>");      
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);      
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            String group = matcher.group();
            System.out.println("start = "+start+" end = "+end+"" +"***GROUP = "+group);

            String substring = sample.substring(start, end);
            System.out.println(" Substring = "+substring);
            String replacedSubString = substring.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");  
            System.out.println("Replaced Substring = "+replacedSubString);

            sample.replace(start, end, replacedSubString);
            System.out.println(" NEW SAMPLE = "+sample);

        }
        System.out.println("********WHILE OVER ********");
        return sample.toString();
    }

}
```

I am getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at line `while (matcher.find())`. I am currently using java Pattern and Matcher to find `nbsp`; and the replace it with `" "`. Does anyone know what causes this ? What should I do to remove the extra `nbsp`; from my string ?

Thanks

Comment: If you simply want to remove all the "&nbsp" why can't you use String.replaceAll("&nbsp;",""); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matcher.reset();` after `sample.replace(start, end, replacedSubString);`

This is because when you replace the string **sample**, the `end` would point to an  **invalid** position.So,you need to use  `matcher.reset();` after every `replace`.

For example if start is 0 and end is 5 and when you replace `&nbsp;` with ,the end would point to an invalid position and then `find` method would throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception if end points to position outside the string length.

---

If string is huge,reset can cause a major performance bottleneck because `reset` would again start matching from beginning.You can instead use

```
 matcher.region(start,sample.length());
```

This would start matching from the last matched position!

Comment: `reset` will make the `Matcher` go back to the beginning, which will make it retries matching the positions that it has processed in previous run.

Comment: Thanks Anirudh, adding matcher.reset(); after replace, worked. I can successfully replace all &nbsp in HTML code

Comment: @sandeepk: Note that it is potentially inefficient on long string, since you are redoing the work for the part of strings that you have visited before.

Comment: @nhahtdh i have addressed that problem in the answer..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// change the group and it is source string is automatically updated
```

There is no way what so ever to change any string in Java, so what you're asking for is impossible.

To remove or replace a pattern with a string can be achieved with a call like

```
someString = someString.replaceAll(toReplace, replacement);
```

To transform the matched substring, as seems to be indicated by your line

```
m.group().replaceAll("something","");
```

The best solution is probably to use a `StringBuffer` for the result

```
Matcher.appendReplacement and Matcher.appendTail.
```

Example:

```
String regex = "ipsum";
String sourceString = "lorem ipsum dolor sit";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    // For example: transform match to upper case
    String replacement = m.group().toUpperCase();
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}

m.appendTail(sb);

sourceString = sb.toString();

System.out.println(sourceString); // "lorem IPSUM dolor sit"
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. After adding matcher.reset(); after replace statement, fixed the error. I am using StringBuffer for manipulation and the returning String latter using toString(); method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `StringBuffer` to hold the replaced string, then use [`appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`appendTail(StringBuffer sb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) methods in `Matcher` class to do the replacement. There is probably way to do this in-place, but the approach above is the most straight-forward way to do this.

This is your `checkRegex` method re-written:

```
private static String checkRegex(String inputString){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]+?&nbsp;[^<]+?>");      
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

    // Create a new StringBuffer to hold the string after replacement
    StringBuffer replacedString = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        // matcher.group() returns the substring that matches the whole regex
        String substring = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(" Substring = "+substring);

        String replacedSubstring = substring.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," "); 
        System.out.println("Replaced Substring = "+replacedSubstring);


        // appendReplacement is a clean approach to append the text which comes
        // before a match, and append the replacement text for the matched text

        // Note that appendReplacement will interpret $ in the replacement string
        // with special meaning (for referring to text matched by capturing group).
        // Matcher.quoteReplacement is necessary to provide a literal string as
        // replacement
        matcher.appendReplacement(replacedString, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacedSubstring));

        System.out.println(" NEW SAMPLE = "+replacedString);
    }

    // appendTail is used to append the text after the last match to the
    // replaced string.
    matcher.appendTail(replacedString);

    System.out.println("********WHILE OVER ********");
    return replacedString.toString();
}
```